# Unicode error xlwings

Tags: xlwings

I'm relatively new to programming so I'm sorry if I don't provide enough information. OS: Mac OS X 10.10.3. From Excel (2011, 14.4.5) I'm calling python xlwings (0.3.5).

The objective is to print a string with a danish character. 
The VBA code:

```
Sub PrintText()
RunPython ("import test_file; test_file.print_text()")
End Sub
```

Python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from xlwings import Workbook, Sheet, Range, Chart


def print_text():
    wb = Workbook.caller()  # Creates a connection with a new workbook
    print('å')
```

Output (unfortunately I don't have point's for posting picture):

> Error
>
> line 7, in print_text print('\xe5')
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe5' in
>   position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

I also wonder why the dialog box shows 'Error', when there is no error (for example print('a')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with unicode in Python, you've got two possibilities: either use Python 3 where things usually just work or prepend a `u` in front of our string in Python 2 to make them unicode: `u'å'`, see also the related discussion [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/117).

As for the other question: True, this is not ideal: the (error) popup on Mac currently shows anything that goes to stdout, which includes print messages. The last bullet of these [release notes](http://docs.xlwings.org/whatsnew.html#id12) show how to mute the pop-up altogether (as a current workaround).

Update: Here's a sample script with unicode for Python 3 (to be called from Excel):

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Range
def print_text():
    wb = Workbook.caller()
    Range('A1').value = 'å'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm running Python 3.4.2 (confirmed with `print(sys.version)`. As mentioned in the link, I also tried using unicode `print(str("å", 'utf-8'))`, but gives me the error: TypeError: decoding str is not supported.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a sample - I think you're looking too far: when working with Excel, you shouldn't really need `print` - you would work with the cells directly. Makes sense?

Comment: I understand now - thanks for the excellent answer and an awesome tool!